# Are there neural networks with 3-dimensional topologies?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, reference-request

The topologies (or architectures) of the neural networks that I have seen so far are only 2-dimensional. So, are there neural networks whose topology is 3-dimensional (i.e. they have a width, height, and depth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. *Convolutional neural networks* are usually 3-dimensional. In fact, they usually deal with images (e.g. RGB images), which can already be 3-dimensional.